# Programming Keyboard what to choose

Tags: keyboard

I can't make up my mind regarding the choice of a new keyboard. In my daily life I am a programmer which as you all know requires the extensive use of brackets etc... I have tried several keyboards in low and high price ranges.

At this moment I am using a low profile Logitech keyboard which I like because I got the idea that low profile keys are causing less finger tip pain when I type for longer periods of time. However I also feel that with a low profile keyboard I seem to be making quit a lot of typo's compered to high/normal height.

Therefore I was wondering about your experience / tips regarding the following.

- Low profile vs Mechanical
- Any knowledge of keyboards that are suited for programming (special character key placement)
- Any other useful info about programming keyboards you might find useful

Thank you for reading!

Comment: is ergonomics in general a factor? (it should be...)

Comment: also, have you went through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187681/where-can-i-find-a-compact-programming-keyboard-with-logical-key-placement?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459363/which-professional-keyboard-are-you-using?rq=1), any reason this question is not a duplicate?

Comment: That topic was nearly 5 years old with the rate that technology is going i thought it to be better to open a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a happy hacking professional 2 keyboard, it is a little expensive ($270) but worth it.  The keyboard was made by a computer scientist and was made to be used in vi text editor (you can google it and check out its layout).  I started using the keyboard after coming from a mechanical keyboard, and I have to say it is the best keyboard I have used for programming.  You will absolutely love the keyboard after about three weeks of use, before that you will feel bipolar about it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Since I love working in Vim and use several operating systems this seems to be the ultimate keyboard.

Comment: Ya I started using vim just because of the keyboard it improved my productivity by a lot.  Just remember I (and others) have had buyers remorse for about 3 weeks, afters that you begin to love it and cannot stop typing on it :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your observation that low profile keys seem to create typos.  I think that part of the problem is that because the keys are dead flat with no curvature, it is hard to quickly place fingers in the correct place.  As programmer's typing is a huge part of what we do, so we need to be able to type quickly, accurately and without discomfort.

12 months ago I changed to a Filco mechanical keyboard (w. brown switches) and have never looked back.

- My typing accuracy has increased
- I do not experience any hand discomfort
- The keyboard is pleasure to type on
- The keyboard should last a long time

I have also purchased a Leopold keyboard for work at home.  The downsides to these keyboards are:

- Noisy
- Cost
- Filco large keys sometimes get squeeky - silcone lubricant fixes this